# Query in prolog regarding fact and list

Tags: prolog

I am new in Prolog and I am stucked in a problem. I have following facts:

```
_________________
likes(a,apple).
likes(a,banana).
likes(a,orange).
_________________
```

and my query will be:

```
counts(a,Var).
```

where `Var = [apple,banana,orange]`. I don't want in this manner that

```
Var=apple ;
Var=banana;
Var=orange;
```

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to get? Is it the count of people who like apple/banana/orange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would resort to the almighty `findall/3` to solve your problem.

```
?- findall(Fruit, likes(a, Fruit), Fruits), length(Fruits, N).

Fruits = [apple,banana,orange]
N = 3
```

So your `counts(a, Var)` is just a `findall/3` call (even if it really collects instead of counting):

```
counts(Person, Fruits) :- findall(Fruit, likes(Person, Fruit), Fruits).
```

And you get the following as a result:

```
?- counts(a, Var).

Var = [apple,banana,orange]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to count number of entities that like fruits given as a list. So, then the code will be something like this:

```
likes(a,apple).
likes(a,banana).
likes(a,orange).

counts(a, [_], 1).
counts(a, [H|T], Count) :- likes(a, H), counts(a, T, Count1), Count is 1 + Count1, !.
```